# Unexpired Activation Key for 10.3.1 suddenly stops working

Tags: licensing

Today my unexpired Activation Key for *Mathematica* 10.3.1 suddenly stopped working When I opened *Mathematica*, I got a "Wolfram Product Activation" pop-up asking for the key. When I typed it in, I was told it was for 10.3, not 10.3.1.

I cannot access my product pages at user.wolfram.com; when I try, I get a "system down for maintenance" message.

Could that be the issue: at startup, *Mathematica* checks on-line against what's registered at Wolfram but, since their site is down, it cannot verify the key?

Another possibility: I had to reinstall OS X 10.11.3 on my Mac because of a bug Apple unwittingly introduced in a "silent" automatic security update. I think that changed the MathID. I did try to use the on-line Wolfram System Transfer Form but got an "unknown error" when I submitted the filled-out form. Beginning to sound like serious server trouble at WRI.

Anybody else experiencing the issue?

(Sorry to post here. It being the weekend, WRI tech support is of course unavailable.)

Comment: I experienced something similar. I own a students desktop version and yesterday the system started stating "..kernel was not able to start due to licencing terms...".
When I reboot my laptop its running again for some hrs and than the same again. I own a valid and licenced version. Already sent a request to support.

Comment: Now, several hours later, my same Activation Key is being accepted. Suspect the trouble was indeed the Wolfram server outage.